# Link Emoji Selector Input to Variable

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui

I am making a swiftUI app and I need a button that when pressed will

1. Open the default macOS emoji selector
2. When an emoji is chosen, link that emoji to the variable "text"
3. Change the button label to "text"

I have managed to do this, however, it requires a text field. Users are able to see this text field, and edit it as well as put more than 1 emoji. I do not want this.

I would like something like this:

[MacOS Reminders List Icon - Emoji Selection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T7Nug.png)

Here is my code

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var text: String = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack {
            
                TextField("", text: $text)
                Button(text) {
                    // Show character palette for the focused text field
                    NSApp.orderFrontCharacterPalette($text)
                    
                }.frame(width: 30, height: 30)
                .buttonBorderShape(.circle)
            

                Button("Print Emoji") {
                print(text)
            }.padding()
        }.padding()
        
    }
}
```

How do I get rid of the text field while still getting the same output, using the default emoji selector. I am ok with keeping the textfield if the user can not see it, you can only type in it by selecting an emoji, only one character is allowed, and when a second emoji is selected the variable is replaced.

Answer (score 0):

It seems there is no native way to do this in SwiftUI. However, there are a few libraries [such as this one](https://github.com/Kyome22/EmojiPalette) that do what you want. Remember to import the package first!

Example code:

```
import SwiftUI
import EmojiPalette

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var text: String = ""
    @State var showSheet = true
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button(text) {
                showSheet.toggle()
            }
            .frame(width: 30, height: 30)
            .buttonBorderShape(.circle)
            .emojiPalette(selectedEmoji: $text, isPresented: $showSheet)
            Button("Print Emoji") {
                print(text)
            }
            .padding()
        }
        .padding()
    }
}
```

Comment: I need it to be a native version, it is possible to do it with a text field, ik because I did that. How would I make a text field uneditable except to a functionn though, and hide the cursor?

Comment: I have added a new answer that does this. Let me know if you have any questions!

Answer (score 0):

Here is some code that does what you want without external packages/libraries. I have hidden the `TextField` with the `opacity` modifier, and set it so that the user automatically focuses on it. Also, the `textVar` variable resets to its last character (the newly inputted one) every time it is changed. Hope this helps!

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    enum FocusedField {
        case textVar
    }
    @State private var textVar: String = ""
    @FocusState private var focusedField: FocusedField?
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            TextField("", text: $textVar)
                .opacity(0)
                .focused($focusedField, equals: .textVar)
            Button(textVar) {
                // Show character palette for the focused text field
                NSApp.orderFrontCharacterPalette($textVar)
            }
            .frame(width: 30, height: 30)
            .buttonBorderShape(.circle)
            .onChange(of: textVar) { _, _ in
                if (textVar != "") {
                    textVar = String(textVar.last!)
                }
            }
            Button("Print Emoji") {
                print(textVar)
            }
            .padding()
        }
        .onAppear {
            focusedField = .textVar
        }
        .padding()
    }
}
```

Comment: HI. Thank you so much for your response. Unfortunately, that does not work, because when I hover over the text field I am able to click on it, and edit it. Is there a way to make it only editable to the NSApp function and make the cursor when hovering over it the default one (not the i)?

Comment: Try adding a frame modifier to the TextField. This works for me!
Example:
TextField("", text: $textVar)
                .frame(width: 0, height: 0)
                .opacity(0)
                .focused($focusedField, equals: .textVar)

Comment: Thank you for answering. I have one last problem. Once I enter the emoji by pressing the button, if i press it again the emoji selector will not be linked to the textfield. However if I delete the emoji, then press it, it works. This seems to be linked to the frame modifier, how do i fix this. Link to video of it not working: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1fu_fCS0J_qxq0s82iW38FCeUT35D5JYG/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I don't really understand what's wrong in the video... It seems to be working in it?

Comment: i would like the emoji selector to be shown as pop up. In the video you see it is shown with the popup (first time), the second time it does not, and the third after i delete the text it shows as a pop up. how do u make all three times as a popup?

link:https://drive.google.com/file/d/1zbBfKWNV8Ec79l8kW1NwA6lEsWKOMIUp/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I see. It is difficult for me to reproduce this issue, as on my MacOS/Xcode version the character picker never shows up as a popup, even when the field is empty. Does this only happen with frame set to 0? Also, what is your Xcode and MacOS version?