How to intercept value from NSResponder and use that string?
My goal: I have a macOS app built, and I want to...

Have a button to open the emoji picker (managed this)
When user select an emoji, intercept that value with NSResponder
Then use it on my Button label

The code below is a simplification. I need help: How can I intercept the value from the NSResponder and print it?
import SwiftUI
import AppKit

struct ContentView: View {
    private let emojiResponder = EmojiResponder()
    
    var body: some View {
        Button {
            // open the emoji picker
            if let window = NSApplication.shared.keyWindow {
                window.makeFirstResponder(emojiResponder)
                DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.1) {
                    NSApp.orderFrontCharacterPalette(nil)
                }
            }
        } label: {
            Text("Emoji?")
        }
        .onAppear {
            emojiResponder.onEmojiSelected = { selectedEmoji in
                print(selectedEmoji)
            }
        }
    }
}

// Custom Emoji NSResponder
class EmojiResponder: NSResponder {
    var onEmojiSelected: ((String) -> Void)?
    
    // use insertTest method from NSResponder
    // I assume this allows me to get the input 
    override func insertText(_ insertString: Any) {
        guard let selectedEmoji = insertString as? String else { return }
        onEmojiSelected?(selectedEmoji)
        print(selectedEmoji)
    }
}

Can anyone give me a pointer on how to solve this?
What happens now: The emoji picker is opened, but nothing happens after I select an emoji
Note: I'm using the solution from this discussion - https://stackoverflow.com/a/77797594/5133585. But I'm hoping a solution without a hidden TextField.

The reason I don't want to use a TextField here:
I have a list that loops through an array. On each row, there are 3 TextFields:
[ emoji ] —— [ name ] —— [ date ]
When I select a row and press enter on macOS, it focuses on the emoji textfield. What I want is to focus on the name TextField. Hence, I'm hoping to remove this emoji TextField and solve that problem.

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/77797594/5133585

Hi @Sweeper - I should've said that I'm using that solution. It works. But it's a bit hacky with a hidden text field. I'm trying to figure out another solution that doesn't involve TextField. I don't know if button can be the First Responder.

What do you mean by "When I select and press enter on macOS, it focuses on the emoji textfield"? What are you selecting?

@Sweeper - Given I have a selectable list, each row has 3 TextFields. When I select the row (from the list) and press enter. Then macOS automatically focuses on the first TextField (the emoji) I hope this clarifies.

The emoji picker must focus on something, and it has to be something you have control over, in order to get what is selected.
If you don't like to focus a hidden TextField, you can focus on the button that opens up the emoji picker. Create an NSButton subclass that conforms to NSTextInputClient, like in this answer, and wrap it in a NSViewRepresentable.
struct EmojiButton: NSViewRepresentable {
    // I chose to use a callback closure here
    // but you can easily make this into a @Binding if you prefer that
    let onSelectEmoji: (String) -> Void
    
    func makeNSView(context: Context) -> TextReceiverButton {
        context.coordinator.button
    }
    
    func updateNSView(_ nsView: TextReceiverButton, context: Context) {
        nsView.receiveText = onSelectEmoji
    }
    
    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator()
    }
    
    @MainActor
    class Coordinator: NSObject {
        let button = TextReceiverButton(title: "Emoji", target: nil, action: nil)
        
        override init() {
            super.init()
            button.target = self
            button.action = #selector(displayEmojiInButton(_:))
        }
        
        @objc func displayEmojiInButton(_ sender: Any) {
            NSApp.orderFrontCharacterPalette(nil)
            Task {
                // this has to be done asynchronously, as in your attempt
                button.window?.makeFirstResponder(button)
            }
        }
    }
}

class TextReceiverButton: NSButton, NSTextInputClient {
    var receiveText: ((String) -> Void)?
    
    nonisolated func setMarkedText(_ string: Any, selectedRange: NSRange, replacementRange: NSRange) {
        
    }
    
    nonisolated func unmarkText() {
        
    }
    
    nonisolated func selectedRange() -> NSRange {
        .init()
    }
    
    nonisolated func markedRange() -> NSRange {
        .init()
    }
    
    nonisolated func hasMarkedText() -> Bool {
        false
    }
    
    nonisolated func attributedSubstring(forProposedRange range: NSRange, actualRange: NSRangePointer?) -> NSAttributedString? {
        nil
    }
    
    nonisolated func firstRect(forCharacterRange range: NSRange, actualRange: NSRangePointer?) -> NSRect {
        .zero
    }
    
    nonisolated func characterIndex(for point: NSPoint) -> Int {
        0
    }

    nonisolated func insertText(_ string: Any, replacementRange: NSRange) {
        if let receivedText = string as? String {
            Task { @MainActor in
                receiveText?(receivedText)
            }
        }
    }
    

    nonisolated func validAttributesForMarkedText() -> [NSAttributedString.Key] {
        return [.font, .paragraphStyle, .writingDirection]
    }
}

Since you mentioned a selectable List with rows containing text fields, here is an example usage in a similar situation. This simply prints out the selected emoji.
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var text = ""
    @State var selection: Int?
    
    var body: some View {
        List(selection: $selection) {
            ForEach(0..<10) { i in Row().tag(i) }
        }
    }
}

struct Row: View {
    @State var name = ""
    @State var date = ""
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            EmojiButton { 
                print("Selected", $0)
            }
            TextField("Name", text: $name)
            TextField("Date", text: $date)
        }
    }
}


To have the emoji picker show up as a pop up, the previously-focused view before doing orderFrontCharacterPalette must be a text field. So if you want the popup to show up on the button, you still have to put an invisible NSTextView at the centre of the button.
Perhaps since this text field is on the AppKit side, SwiftUI doesn't know about it, and will not have the undesirable focus behaviour when pressing the return key.
When the button is pressed, set the first responder to the invisible text view, then asynchronously call orderFrontCharacterPalette.
Here is an example implementation.
struct EmojiButton: NSViewRepresentable {
    let onSelectEmoji: (String) -> Void
    
    func makeNSView(context: Context) -> NSView {
        context.coordinator.view
    }
    
    func updateNSView(_ nsView: NSView, context: Context) {
        context.coordinator.textView.receiveText = onSelectEmoji
    }
    
    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator()
    }
    
    @MainActor
    class Coordinator: NSObject {
        let button = NSButton(title: "Emoji", target: nil, action: nil)
        let textView = TextReceiverView(frame: .init(x: 0, y: 0, width: 1, height: 1))
        let view = NSView()
        
        override init() {
            super.init()
            
            button.target = self
            button.action = #selector(displayEmojiInButton(_:))
            
            // remove the cursor
            textView.insertionPointColor = .clear
            
            button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            textView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            // add the textView first so the button goes above it
            view.addSubview(textView)
            view.addSubview(button)
            NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
                button.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor),
                button.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.rightAnchor),
                button.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor),
                button.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor),
                textView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 1),
                textView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 1),
                textView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor),
                textView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor),
            ])
        }
        
        @objc func displayEmojiInButton(_ sender: Any) {
            button.window?.makeFirstResponder(textView)
            Task {
                try await Task.sleep(for: .milliseconds(100))
                NSApp.orderFrontCharacterPalette(nil)
            }
        }
    }
}

class TextReceiverView: NSTextView {
    
    var receiveText: ((String) -> Void)?

    override func insertText(_ string: Any, replacementRange: NSRange) {
        if let receivedText = string as? String {
            receiveText?(receivedText)
        }
    }
}


Thank you. This is going in the right direction. The only problem: The emoji picker appears as a window. The technique from this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77797594/5133585 makes the character palette (emoji picker) appear as a tooltip. (This is great because it follows the app window.) Is this feasible? Otherwise, I might need to think of different approach

@dev_dev it does show a tooltip sometimes. It seems to depend on what you were focusing on before you press the button. If the focus were on something from which a tooltip can be shown, the tooltip will be shown from there.

@dev_dev I have updated the answer to use a rather different approach. Try that.

you're the best, thank you so much. I've tried this on a new project file, and it works really well. This has set me on the right path. I will try it in my real project. It seems like learning AppKit will be beneficial in a case like this. I will try my best to learn AppKit
